# Identify Ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible, yaml, lint, ansible-lint

I would like to add an automatic syntax check (as CI process) for all the Ansible playbooks in my project, using `ansible-lint`. 
There are playbooks in several directories in the project, so I thought of using something like `locate *.yml`. However, the problem is that there are some other YAML files in my project, which are not Ansible playbooks, and therefore I would not want `ansible-lint` to test those files(as it will always fail).

Is there any way to distinguish between ansible playbooks and regular YAML files?

Comment: you can use `tasks` as well as `hosts`.I would prefer `tasks` with `roles`

Comment: @error404 What do you mean `tasks` with `roles`?

Comment: just like hosts `tasks` and `roles` are keyword every ansible playbook has in it.

Comment: @error404 Oh, I get it. So how for example can I `grep` for files with both `- hosts:` and `tasks`?

Comment: egrep “hosts|tasks”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume all your ansible-playbooks contain something like `- hosts`, perhaps you can use `grep` for that search query. And then perform the linter on the found files with `| xargs ansible-lint`.

So forget the `.yaml` file extension, but take another approach. You'll figure it out :)

Comment: If I'm trying to do something like `grep -rwl '- hosts:'` I get an error: `grep: invalid option -- ' '`, but without the `-` it works fine. Any way to include the `-`?

Comment: `grep -rwl -- '- hosts:'`

Comment: My plays tend to begin with `- name: something` rather than `- hosts: something`, so I have to search without the hyphen. That picks up inventories too. But then inventories can be identified as having `all:` near the beginning.